# Can anybody give me example of processing GeoPackage file with Geotools?

Tags: java, geotools, geopackage

I have two things I want to perform with geopackage files. Only vector polygone layers I want to work with.
1/ access specific layer within given geopackage and retrieve rows from it (attribute table when working in QGIS)
2/ I have coordinates and I want to search for polygone in which the point exists, in specific layer of geopackage. I want to retrieve whole row of such polygone (like in QGIS layer's attribute table).
I know the GeoTools covers this functionality, but never used such geo library and I do not know how to work with it.
When I copied some examples from web, there are still occuring some errors.
I work in NetBeans, I download the GeoTools jars, created new Library and added it to my project.
[project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzTya.png)
Can anybody give me complete functioning example?

I tried this piece of code:

```
GeoPackageReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new GeoPackageReader(getClass().getResource("USJ_hranice_0.gpkg"), null);
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(reader.getGridCoverageNames()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

And this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/measure/UnconvertibleException
    at org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultEngineeringCRS.<clinit>(DefaultEngineeringCRS.java:78)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory.<clinit>(CartesianAuthorityFactory.java:54)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridFormat.<clinit>(AbstractGridFormat.java:89)
    at org.geotools.geopkg.mosaic.GeoPackageReader.<init>(GeoPackageReader.java:102)
    at Main.Test.test(Test.java:22)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.measure.UnconvertibleException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: That is a Java version or lib mismatch. `I download the GeoTools jars`, probably the wrong one. You should go with maven or similiar https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/netbeans.html

Comment: "USJ_hranice_0.gpkg".  should be the fully qualified class name of which it should be a .class but without the .class extension and  it also must have all its hierarchy names. If it is in a .jar the jar should been notified on the startup command line so getResource can look inside it for the class. If your resource is a resource not a class then it should been package in (for web server .war)  the META-INF directory and perhaps some notification in the .jar manifest with it accord the rules for jars, or in a special folder in the jar packaging structure e.g. named "resources"

Comment: Opening a GeoPackage.  http://www.geopackage.org/guidance/getting-started.html.     The .gpkg file is for use with SQLite fdtabase

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445716/bulk-writing-to-geopackage-with-geotools - contains a pretty good example - as @PeterMmm says you'll want to use Maven and a pom file to handle the dependencies required for a GeoTools project.